# Python double list to text file

Tags: python, file

so I have a list in this format:

```
[(532, 'working'), (417, 'texting')]
```

And I want to write it in a text file in this format:

```
532 working

417 texting
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin more things but everything gets me an error

Comment: Then you need to update your question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation works as expected:

```
input = [(532, 'working'), (417, 'texting')]

with open("output.txt", "w") as opened_file:
    for element in input:
        opened_file.write("%s %s\n" % (element[0], element[1]))
```

Output:

```
>>>cat output.txt 
532 working
417 texting
```